# How to create custom commands in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

Can anyone guide me to create custom commands in Unix/Linux.

Comment: For future reference, you should check out the facts page. It explains the things you should put in your questions. (such as posting the things that you have researched & tried). That's likely why someone gave this question a down vote.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Create a bash script in your /usr/bin folder, it should look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
Whatever combination of commands you want to run when you type this thing.
```

Its really that easy.

Just name the bash script what you want to type in to the terminal, and make it excecutable: `chmod +x filename` and you're good to go!

Comment: execute with `./filename`

Comment: /usr/bin folder is intended for the Linux distributor. ~/bin is the right place to put personal stuff and /usr/local/bin is for custom software intended for everyone on the system to use. One would like to keep a degree of logical separation / easy navigation over their own files.

Answer (score 60):

1. Create a directory say "bin" under your home directory.
2. Update your path variable to include this bin directory. Put this in `.profile` or `.bash_profle` file to make it permanent.

   `export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin"`
3. Create a script say, "hello" and keep it in your bin directory. Give execute permission to the hello script by `$ chmod +x hello`.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash    
   echo My first program
   ```
4. Reload `.profile` or `.bash_profle`:

   `$ . ~/.bash_profile`
5. From any directory, you simply type:

   ```
   $ hello
   My first program
   ```

Comment: I know this is very old but I have seen your suggestion of creating a `bin` folder in a lot of answers here. Is there any problem if it's `.bin` instead of `bin`?. I am really picky about how my `home` looks and I dont want an extra folder just because.

Comment: I have tried using this unsuccessfully and was very frustrated for a while thinking there was something wrong with my `zsh` install or `$PATH` but it ended up being that the `chmod -x hello` wasn't working, neither does a capital `-X`. Instead I tried `chmod 755 hello`, while I am not sure of the security risks in regards to this command it actually let me run `hello`. Does anyone have an explanation for this? I am assuming it is a problem in regards to age?

Comment: @ConstantFun Use `chmod +x hello` to add 'run' privileges to the script. `chmod -x hello` does the exact opposite - removes the 'run' privileges. (Notice the plus/minus sign difference in the answer and in your comment.)

Answer (score 29):

Easy, create an alias.

Say you want to write a command to cd into your download directory. And you want to call it cdd.

```
alias cdd='cd ~/Downloads'
```

You can create any command you want.

Here is further information:
http://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/alias.html

Comment: This doesn't persist across sessions, though. This command works, but isn't permanent. A more permanent way would be to modify your ~/.bash_aliases file and add the line you suggested there.

Comment: Also works by adding it to your ~/.bashrc file

Comment: @JeffGrimes you can put it in the `~/.profile` file (or `.bashrc` as Deilicia mentioned) and it will be permanent enough. very useful on hostings with limited file editing rights btw

Comment: I think add alias to your .bashrc file is the most elegant and simple way to custom your command. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Most, if not all by now, Linux distributions have a little script in ~/[.bashrc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html) that looks almost identical to this:

```
if [ -e ~/.bash_aliases ]
then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

This merely means you can create your own commands (also known as '`aliases`' usually referred to an existing command with some arguments you always have to use, or a list of commands that have to be executed in order).

Your Linux distribution will most likely not have the .bash_aliases file created in your home, unless you've manually done that already. So to create the file, type in the following command:
`touch ~/.bash_aliases`

Now that file will be executed automatically every time you fire off a new Terminal.

What you can do now is create a list of aliases and add them to that file for later uses. For example, the `rm` (remove) command by default does NOT ask you to confirm your request when you tell it to delete a file/directory. However, there is an argument that tells `rm` to ask you to confirm your request, `-i`. So, `rm -i filePath` will display a message asking you if you were sure you want to delete the specified file. Now, if you were to accidentally delete a file, you will very likely forget to include the `-i` option, and that's where an `alias` becomes very beneficial. Typing the following command

```
echo "alias rm='\rm -i'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

will tell `Bash` that every time you request to delete a file, a confirming message will be displayed to you. Of course, there is a lot more you can do—this is just the basics.

If you want to learn how to use some basic commands (i.e. `cd`, `touch`, `rm`, `mkdir`, `pushd`, `popd`, etc.) and/or more sophisticated ones, I'd recommend a very good book you can have on your bookshelf as a reference called

[a practical guide to linux commands editors and shell programming](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/013308504X), by [Mark G. Sobell](http://www.sobell.com/). ISBN: 978-0133085044

Comment: why the backslash?

Comment: @phil294 perhaps you mean forward slash? So when you see ~/ that is a shortcut to saying /home/yourname/.bashaliases else here is info about backslashes as escape characters: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146663/meaning-of-backslash

Comment: @RobertHoughton thanks! But I guess I had been confused to the backslash inside `rm=\rf` instead. I now know that its purpose is to point to the real `rm` binary (at /usr/bin or wherever), and to ignore any possible functions or other aliases named `rm`.