# Meaning of backslash

Tags: bash, escape-characters

Why the following command prints `Smith` but not `\Smith`?

```
echo \Smith
```

Answer (score 5):

The [backslash is an escape character in the shell syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01) that:

> shall preserve the literal value of the following character, with the exception of a <newline>. ... The <backslash> ... shall be removed

So `\S` means the same thing as `S`, because `S` is not a newline character and also not a shell special character that could be escaped (`$`, `"`, `'`, `{`, `[`, `` ` ``, `\`, `|`, `&`, `;`, `<`, `>`, `(`, `)`, `?`, `*`, `[`, `#`, `~`, `=`, `%`, , or tab). To include a literal backslash in the argument given to `echo`, escape it in turn with `\` or any other quoting operator:

```
echo \\Smith
```

or

```
echo '\Smith'
```

or

```
echo "\Smith"
```

(`\` still retains a special meaning within double quotes, but not when followed by `S`, only when followed by `\`, `` ` ``, `$`, `"` or newline).

Now, many `echo` implementations also treat `\` specially when found in their argument (though generally not when followed by `S`, though there's no guarantee), so you may want to use `printf` instead:

```
printf '%s\n' '\Smith'
```

*note: this is the specified behavior for your example unquoted case, but it can change if it is otherwise quoted or `read` in from a file*

Answer (score 2):

`\S` escapes the `S`, which is not a special character, thus gives `S`. You need to double the backslash to print it: `echo \\Smith`

EDIT: But more generally, it's better to use `printf`. See the difference between `echo x\\by`, which outputs "y" (the "x" gets overwritten by the backspace `\b`) with some versions of `echo` (dash, zsh), and `printf "%s\n" x\\by`, which outputs "x\by".