# How to add a custom command to Linux repositories for everyone to download

Tags: linux, repository

I went through two posts which tell about how one can make a Linux command.
Here are the posts:
[Creating a custom Linux commmand](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux),
[Creating Custom Linux Command](https://medium.com/devnetwork/how-to-create-your-own-custom-terminal-commands-c5008782a78e)

I wanted to know how can I make such commands available to everyone for download.
My goal is to create a simple C++ graphics 2D game and run it as a command in Linux. Also, I wanted it to be available for everyone to use.
Do I have to use git for it to be available for everyone and provide a simple installer for it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Providing an installation package requires familiarity with several different Linux distributions, because you will have to create packages  for each family. But this is a bit premature IMHO.

To share the source code, you would create a project on Gitlab.com, Github.com,  or similar, with the necessary scripts to let people compile a version for their own platform (automake, autoconf, and the like).