# How can I setup my HPUX profile to use the Linux equivalent of the repeatable commands from history (like !3)?

Tags: linux, hp-ux

One thing I really like from Linux is to be able to view my history with the "history" command, and then type !# where # is the command from my history that I would like to run. Unfortunately, while HPUX does have a history command, it seems I cannot repeat a command the same way I can in Linux using !#.

Is there a way I can implement this in HPUX? So far, the best option I have found would be to create a custom command: [How to create custom commands in Unix/Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux)

My approach would be to have a custom command in the format of !n where n is an integer that gets parsed out. The command corresponding to n is parsed from the history and ran. While this is doable, it sure feels like I am reinventing the wheel.

Is there a better way to achieve this result? What can I do to repeat commands from my history in HPUX?

Comment: HPUX has ksh, which should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Maybe I'm missing something here, but it seems like ksh is not providing the functionality I need. I type "ksh" at the prompt, the prompt changes, so I assume I'm now using ksh. However, when I type !212 to execute a previous command, I get the following: "ksh: !212: not found". Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC `ksh` (based on Korn 88) or even `ksh93` don't offer the advanced history features that `bash` does.

Comment: Thank you so much, that clarifies things for me!

Answer (score 0):

The standard HP-UX Posix shell isn't a `bash` port and the `history` command behavior you're looking for requires it.

Compiling `bash` from source on HP-UX isn't trivial. It requires an HP-UX ANSII C compiler and several dependencies and patches. Fortunately, if you are running HP-UX 11i.v3, recent binaries are available for installation on Itanium class servers from the [HP-UX Porting and Archive Centre](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/); namely:

[bash-4.4.012](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Shells/bash-4.4.012/)

[bash-5.0.018](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Shells/bash-5.0.018/)

[bash-5.1.16](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Shells/bash-5.1.16/)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have limited permissions on this system, and I don't think compiling bash would be an option. In that case, do you think my best bet would be to just create a custom command after all?

Comment: I suggest that you download a pre-compiled binary from the HP-UX Porting Centre. As I said, compiling from source will be non-trivial and needless for your purposes.

Comment: Of course, if you have "limited permissions" on your server, ask your system administrator to perform the download and `swinstall`.