# How to create custom math command in Unix/Linux?

Tags: terminal, command

So, I want to make a factorial command for the linux terminal, and I want to be able to run it like this:

```
$ factorial 5
120
```

However, when I look at questions about this, I only see commands that runs a SET of commands, like for example a command that changes your directory to `~/Downloads` and echoes "Went to Downloads!"

How can I make the factorial function as a command, and if this is a duplicate, could you at least tell me why it is a duplicate?

Comment: Some shell scripts just run a list of commands. But shell also has many built-in commands of its own, to do arithmetic, make loop constructs, and format text. For `factorial 5`, you would just want a `for` loop that contained a multiply operation, and counted up to 5.

Comment: Alright, the thing is, in what type of programming language would I do so?

Comment: what language do you **know**? Use that - but since you said you want to "make a script", assuming you meant shell script, then that's what language you would use

Comment: Python. That's basically it, although I wouldn't be inconvenienced to learn shell script.

Comment: "Alright, the thing is, in what type of programming language would I do so?" – Any programming language you want. If you know any programming language at all, this should be a one-line problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is future me:

- Add a `bin` directory if you haven't already in your home directory by running `mkdir ~/bin` [Cited]
- Afterwards, make a python file that does etc.
- Then, use `cd` to go to your bin directory.
- Then, run `export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin"` (Straight from an answer from cited source)
- Afterwards, make a file in this format:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 [path to python file]
```

- Afterward, run `chmod +x [bin file name goes here]` [Cited]
- Finally, run `. ~/.bash_profile` (Again, straight from citation)

Now, you have made a command that will run the python file.

I do have to cite [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84686/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-unix-linux) Linux-Unix stack exchange question, as I got most of the information here.